# Three-parts correlation or equivalent?

Tags: correlation, signal-processing, association-measure

I'm wondering what's the usual way for detecting "three-parts" association between variables. I'm not even sure about the name, so I apologize for any misunderstandings beforehand. Here is what I want. I  suspect that buried behind some noise is a relation of this kind:

$$s=\begin{cases}
g(b) & \textrm{ if }f(a)\\
h(c) & \textrm{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are "input" signals, $c$ is an "output", $f$ has image $\{0,1\}$ and $g$ and $h$ are monotonic one-variable functions. In other words, $a$ acts as a switch so that in some cases $s$ and $b$ are correlated, and in others $s$ and $c$; but neither $g$, $h$ or $f$ are known beforehand.

Comment: I don't understand what do mean by the if/else clause (especially if $f$,$g$,$e$ are real functions).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I have edited the question to use mathematical notation, and $f$ is indeed a Boolean function (my fault before).  Hope the edit helps. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it clarifies a lot. While both programming and mathematical notations are clear, the rest was not (what is know and what unknown, what are the types of functions/variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try measuring dependences of $(s, b)$ and $(s,c)$ for fixed $a$.

For your case ($g$ and $h$ are monotonic real-valued functions) perhaps the best way is to use [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient).

So you get the coefficients $\rho_{s,b}(a)$ and $\rho_{s,c}(a)$ as functions of $a$. If there is such switching you get $$\max\{|\rho_{s,b}(a)|, |\rho_{s,c}(a)|\} = 1$$  for all $a$.

However, as you know $f,g$ and $h$ beforehand, why not just measure how well does it fit, e.g. using
$$\langle |s_{measured}-s_{expected}(a,b,c)|^2\rangle$$
or Pearson's correlation?

Comment: I think this will do it. I really don't know f, g or h, but if I use Spearman's rcc then I can proceed. Thanks for your answer!